# 'Normalized' NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have to parse strings like `2012-06-06T18:00:00` or `2012-06-06` without any timezone information. When I parse this the date formatter uses the local timezone and takes DST into account.

But what the date actually means is that this event occurs on `2012-06-06` not depending on the timezone, but on `2012-06-06T00:00:00` in every timezone.

Should I store the year/month/day values separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same time in different time zones will correspond to different absolute times (which are represented by NSDate). So one NSDate object cannot represent what you are trying to represent. You will need one NSDate per time zone you are interested in.

You can create an NSDateComponent instance with your string. Then use NSCalender with the locale (time zone) you want to transform those date components into an NSDate (a point in time).

Comment: You can make the NSDateFormatter with locale GMT, then make an NSDate, then make an NSCalender with locale GMT, and get the NSDateComponents from that (as long as you have the same locale in the NSDateFormatter and the NSCalender you will get the NSDateComponents you want). No need to parse by hand.